# how to set variables in a session?

Tags: php, html, session, session-variables

hello i would like to use sessions for setting the language settings.

so i will get a preferred language from http_language_accept:

```
if (isset($_SERVER["HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE"])){
    $max   = 0.0;
    $languages = explode(",", (strtolower($_SERVER["HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE"])));
    foreach($languages as $language){
        $language = explode(';', $language);
        $q    = (isset($language[1])) ? ((float) $language[1]) : 1.0;
        if ($q > $max){
            $max = $q;
            $pref_language = $language[0];
        }
    }
    $pref_language = trim($pref_language);
}
```

now i would like to check whether already a setting saved from a previous visit is saved:

```
if (isset($_SESSION['pref_lang'])){
    $_SESSION['pref_lang'] = $pref_language;
}
```

this is the first problem. when calling the page it will display error 500.

further i would like to change the $pref_language when sending a $_POST:

so i have this code:

```
$one = $_POST['one'];

if(isset($_SESSION['pref_lang']) AND isset($one) ){
    $_SESSION['pref_lang'] = 'one';
    $_SESSION['pref_lang'] = $pref_language;
}
```

it would be nice when somebody could tell me if this is the right way to set and change variables while using sessions.

thanks alot.

UPDATE:

okay regarding to the answers i used the method of user olaf dietsche.

so i did it like that:

```
if (!isset($_SESSION['pref_lang'])){ //if the session does not exist
    if (isset($pref_language)){ //but the given $pref_language from above
        $_SESSION['pref_lang'] = $pref_language; //the session will be registered with the value of $pref_language
    }
}else{ 
    if (isset($_SESSION['pref_lang'])){ //in case of that an existing session from a previous visit
        if (isset($pref_language)){ //and the pref_language is set from above
            $_SESSION['pref_lang'] = $pref_language; //the session will be given a variable
            if (isset($one)){ // this will be the problem now when isset $_post 
                    $pref_language = 'one'; //$pref_language or even session will get a new value
                }
                if (isset($two)){
                    $pref_language = 'two';
                }



}
```

Comment: `it will display error 500` check your error log to see the message.

Comment: Error 500 are not likely to be caused by sessions.It can be some server error,you can start by checking if .htaccess is present there.It can have issues.

Comment: error log will not be shown. i used error_reporting(E_ALL); but it wont be directed.. it will be said that the site has a coding mistake.

Comment: @techie_28 PHP errors can cause 500 error in certain setups. My college's server which ran suEXEC would error 500 on PHP errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you look into your web server log, you will see the concrete error message.

I would guess, that in

```
if (isset($_SESSION['pref_lang'])){
    $_SESSION['pref_lang'] = $pref_language;
}
```

`$pref_language` isn't set. Try changing it to

```
if (isset($_SESSION['pref_lang'])){
    if (isset($pref_language))
        $_SESSION['pref_lang'] = $pref_language;
    else
        echo 'pref_language is not set';
}
```

and see if the error is gone. Otherwise as noted, look into your server log.

You don't need to check `isset($_SESSION['pref_lang'])` in the else part again, because you did so already in the if part.

```
session_start();
...
if (!isset($_SESSION['pref_lang'])){ //if the session does not exist
    if (isset($pref_language)){ //but the given $pref_language from above
        $_SESSION['pref_lang'] = $pref_language; //the session will be registered with the value of $pref_language
    }
}else{ 
    //in case of that an existing session from a previous visit
    if (isset($pref_language)){ //and the pref_language is set from above
        $_SESSION['pref_lang'] = $pref_language; //the session will be given a variable
        if (isset($one)){ // this will be the problem now when isset $_post 
            $pref_language = 'one'; //$pref_language or even session will get a new value
        }
        if (isset($two)){
            $pref_language = 'two';
        }
    }
```

Comment: hello and thanks for answering this question. despite adding brackets it wont echo anything. i unset the session by hand also.

Comment: forgot to say that the error is gone but when calling this site it wont display something. the session is empty when i will call and print_r it.

Comment: @bonny Is the error gone *after* changing the code or is it gone without changing anything? When you see no output look into the server's log to see what's wrong.

Comment: the error is gone after changing the code. now i understand you logic behind that. so i will update my question to show details.

Comment: @bonny See modified answer. The code should work so far, but why do you modify `$pref_language` after you have set `$_SESSION['pref_lang']`?

Comment: @bonny In the else part you modify `$pref_language`, when `$one` or `$two` is set.

Comment: this is for the different language options that should be possible. but this is not working at the moment.

Answer (score 0):

you cant check `if (isset($_SESSION['pref_lang']))`

but you must check by the post like that

```
  if (isset($_POST['pref_lang']))

   {
     $_SESSION['pref_lang']) = $_POST['pref_lang']) ;  // HERE you define the session variable
   }
```

and then u can use  `$_SESSION['pref_lang'])` in your code

- the session store data after the post/get submit  so u define the session from the post/get variable